# PopUp to contains other controls like DateTime Picker,dropdownlist

Tags: xamarin.forms

newbie here. I remember in Win10, there is a PopUp UI which can contains many controls like Dropdown box, DatePciker and others. This PopUp can be constructed in Xaml.

I am developing an app for Tablet.
It is possible to use such PopUp in Xamarin forms which contains Dropdown List, DatePicker, Time Picker? It is advisable to do such complex UI ? will it cause problem in Android and iOS?

Problem : How to create PopUp in Xaml

```
so ,I can use a button to open or close it.

var button = new Button {Text = "Show Popup"};
button.Clicked += (s, e) => popup.Show();
```

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.View.PopUpDemo"
             Title="PopUp Demo"
             Icon="itemIcon3">

<Grid>
    <Grid>

        <!--Your Page xaml-->

         <Button x:Name="btnPopUp"  Click="ShowPopUp"/>

    </Grid>

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="##60000000" IsVisible="{Binding GridVisibility}">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame Grid.Column="1" Padding="0"  HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="#e6e6e6">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                 <!--content for popup-->
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

I would like to know :

I am using a normal ContentPage.

1) In it, i place your MarkUp <Grid>  ,I remove <ContentPage.Content>. Is this correct?

2) Is Frame will be the PopUp ? 
3) what code to use in btnPopUp to show the PopUp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it without any performance issue. Either you can use an overlay to show pop up as shown below

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!--Your Page xaml-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="##60000000" IsVisible="{Binding GridVisibility}">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame Grid.Column="1" Padding="0"  HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="#e6e6e6">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                 <!--content for popup-->
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This one is quite simple. Here i have added grid to achieve this. You can also use other layouts. But for performance grid is better as per xamarin team.

For the second grid i have added Visibility property so that you can wire up with any event.
Here i have added backgroundcolor for popup ##60000000 so that when popup appears background will be transparent with light black color effect.

If you need to have same pop up in multiple screens you can use 3rd party plugin  https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup which will make you work easier. For this you have to make a new contentpage, replace the contentpage with

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class=""
         BackgroundColor="##60000000"
         InputTransparent="True"
         HasSystemPadding="True"
         CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False">
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:MoveAnimation
              PositionIn="Bottom"
              PositionOut="Bottom"/>
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>
<Grid>
    <!--your xaml code-->
</Grid>
```

Note:Replace contentPage with PopupPage in youpage.xaml.cs. To get popup effect your layout should be like 1st example i shown. Here you can also get nice animation effects. More details you can see in their site.

Now you can call the pop up by calling:`navigation.PushPopupAsync(new YourContentPage());`

And remove the popup by calling `await PopupNavigation.RemovePageAsync(this);`

Hope this will be useful for you

Comment: please see my update. Would appreciate you can guide me for using your approach first. I wan to show the popup on the same page when user click the button.

Comment: Both the approach will give you the pop up on same page. On using second approach you need to write XAML for pop up only once and you can call it from any page, it will appear as pop. You can try any method. If you are stuck please let me know.

Comment: I m stuck as to how to call the popup in my update and my questions above. can you show me the steps? Thanks

Comment: I have created a demo for the first approach(https://github.com/RenjithPr90/DemoPopUp). For the second approach using library you can refer https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup. Hope this will help you. Thanks